# combobox/ SelectedIndexChanged with SQL

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, combobox

I have 3 different SQL code. I put my 3 text (men, woman, both) in combobox collection. I don't know how to when I select by example Men in combobox, the good SQL code apply.

Men:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, MaritalStatus, Gender 
FROM Employes, Contacts 
WHERE Employes.ContactId = Contacts.ContactID 
  AND Gender = 'M' 
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
```

Woman:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, MaritalStatus, Gender 
FROM Employes, Contacts 
WHERE Employes.ContactId = Contacts.ContactID 
  AND Gender = 'F' 
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
```

Both:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, MaritalStatus, Gender 
FROM Employes, Contacts 
WHERE Employes.ContactId = Contacts.ContactID 
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
```

Look(is in french) (Choisir le sexe= Choose sexe) (Afficher = Show in english)

[image]

Thanks Alot !

Comment: You need to write C# code that acts when a selection (something that uses new System.EventHandler(ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);) is made in the combo box and then runs the corresponding SQL call.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you fill your combobox with three strings `Hommes, Femmes, Tous` then when you receive the event `SelectedIndexChanged` you could write something like this

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // Get the currently selected item in the ListBox.
   string curItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
   string sqlText = "SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, MaritalStatus, Gender " + 
                    "FROM Employes JOIN Contacts ON Employes.ContactId = Contacts.ContactID "
   switch(curItem)
   {
      case "Femmes":
          sqlText += "AND Gender = 'F' ORDER BY LastName, FirstName";
          break;
      case "Hommes":
          sqlText += "AND Gender = 'M' ORDER BY LastName, FirstName";
          break;
      default:
          sqlText += "ORDER BY LastName, FirstName";
   }
   DataTable dt = GetEmployeeList(sqlText);
   ...... // Now fill the datasource of your grid
}
```

EDIT: Uh, just read the @marc_s comment